# Phone Listener logic

Tags: java, android

I have a phone listener with 2 options, ringing and idle.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

1. If do not disturb is not already on.
   The phone rings.
   Do not disturb comes on while the phone rings.
   The phone stops ringing.
   Do not disturb comes off.
2. If do not disturb is already on. Nothing happens.

**What is actually happening:**

1. Works fine.
2. When the phone stops ringing, do not disturb comes off.

**My code sample:**

```
switch (state) {
     case CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                    assert notificationManager != null;
                    if (notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() != INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY &&
                            notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() != INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALARMS &&
                            notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() != INTERRUPTION_FILTER_UNKNOWN &&
                            notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() != INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE) {

    notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE);

                    }
                    break;

      case CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        assert notificationManager != null;
                        notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL);
                    }
```

**What I tried:**
I tried creating a boolean "isActivated" in my first Switch case and passing it to my second Switch case. If isActivated is true, then set interruption filter to All. Else, do nothing. But this had no effect.

I would be grateful for some pointers as I don't understand where my logic is wrong.

EDIT: I have moved the check to see if Do Not Disturb is on before the Phone Listener kicks in, so that nothing happens if DND is already on. This seems to make sense. However, results are inconsistent. Most of the time INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL kicks in when the state goes idle, and occasionally it doesn't.

Here is my listener code:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    dnDisturbOn = notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY ||
            notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALARMS ||
            notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == INTERRUPTION_FILTER_UNKNOWN ||
            notificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter() == INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE;

    if (!dnDisturbOn) {

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if (telephony != null) {
            telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String number) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, number);

                    testNumber(context, state, number);
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why the code as it is should impact on the consistency of the method "testNumber"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have three states.
1.Ringing
2.Idle
3.Idle_do_not_disturb

From first you will go to second when you turn off do not disturb, and from second you can go in first when somebody calls you, and to third when someone turn on do not disturb. From third you can go only in second when somebody turn off do not disturb. I don't know is this what you want, or you want with only two states.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, but how do you implement these rules? For instance, how do you make sure that from third you can only go in second?

Comment: I don't know are we talking about same thing, but if you work with states, you must have something that will trigger change of state. If you are in third state, and it starts ringing you wont react on that, just ignore it. It is something that wont change your state, you are waiting for disturb off, not ringing. When disturb off event happen, than you will change state

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I'll try it tonight and if it works I'll let you know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm struggling with this. Any chance you could give me an example if it's not too much trouble? @Милош

Comment: For example you change this in function that receive event, this is some pseudo code

function(event){
switch (state)
 case Ringing:
  Do something
  if (event.type==disturb_on) state=idle
 case Idle:
  Do something
  if(event.type==disturb_on)state=idle_do_not_disturb
  else if(event.type==ringing)state=Ringing
 case Idle_do_not_disturb:
  Do something
  if (event.type==disturb_off)state=idle;
end switch  
}

Again, I am not sure do I understand what you need to do.

Comment: Many thanks, I appreciate your reply. I have not managed to implement this but thanks.